# Floating point constant

Tags: c, floating-point

For the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 0.7;
    printf("%.10f %.10f\n", 0.7f, a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

> 0.7000000000 0.6999999881

Please explain why `a` is printed as `0.6999999881` while the literal constant is printed as `0.7000000000` ?

Is the use of a floating point constant in this case compiler-dependent?

Comment: @LPs: that's what I thought at first too, but there's a more interesting question here, which is why does the literal constant `0.7f` get printed exactly ? Voting to re-open.

Comment: YMMV: This prints `0.6999999881 0.6999999881` on my machine and on others I have access to. So whatever magic your compiler/C library does, it's not portable.

Comment: It must have something to do with the conversion to `double` that happens for variable argument functions. What compiler are you using? What version of it?

Comment: @dhke: it may be a gcc quirk - what compiler are you using ? gcc seems to exhibit the same behaviour that the OP is seeing: http://ideone.com/eKqmvl

Comment: @PaulR I can guess it is due to the paltform. BTW `f` specifier for literlas define a `float` that has less precision than `double`.

Comment: @paul-r: Tried with gcc 4.7.2 (with glibc), clang 3.4.1 and gcc 4.8.5 (the latter both with FreeBSD libc). Both on amd64, though. I'd guess platform specific libc hackery.

Comment: @LPs The format specifier doesn't matter for `printf` as all `float` values should be converted to `double` in a variable argument function. For `printf` the formats `"%f"` and `"%lf"` are the same.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How the compiler works here? It convert `float` literal to "number" so convert it to `double` after call to `printf`? Or it is directly converted to double due to `printf` call?

Comment: @LPs It's [default argument conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions), all `float` values (literal or variables) are converted and passed as `double`. It seems to me that in the case of the question, the compiler recognizes the literal `0.7f` in the context of the variable argument list, and treats it as a `double` to begin with (i.e. it simply disregards the `f` suffix).

Comment: But a is initialised to 0.7 right! so the output for a also had to be 0.700000000, isn't it?  @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @HARSHPARMAR No, because `a` is a `float` which doesn't have the precision of a `double`, so the value **stored** in `a` is an *approximation* of `0.7`, the stored value can't be changed when its type is converted back to a `double`.

Comment: @PaulR ...and compiling it with C++ it will change output [http://ideone.com/TJ5Ti9](http://ideone.com/TJ5Ti9)

Comment: @2501 Since this seems to be a quirk of the compiler, it's pretty much impossible to give a definitive answer (unless someone from the GCC team reads this question and decides to answer).

Comment: My conclusion: it's probably just a grey area rather than a compiler bug, given that different compilers handle this case differently. Of course if you observe all the usual precautions when dealing with floating point it should never be a problem.

Comment: Looking at [the assembler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#) it seems that `0.7f` is treated differently than 0.7. As I wrote I think is a conversion chain problem: literal to `float`, then `float` to `double` that makes the conversion loose precision. The lower part of `.LC1` is `1610612736` that is `0x60000000` but it should be `1717986918` that is  `0x66666666`, as shown for `.LC2` clang has the same behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's not a quirk, it's strict adherence to the C standard.

Answer (score 4):

Obtaining “0.7000000000” as the string printed for `printf("%.10f",0.7f)` is normal behavior if the compiler defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` as 1 or 2.

Indeed, in that mode, floating-point constants can be represented at a precision [beyond](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2p9) that of their type (C11 5.2.4.2.2:9):

> Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating **constants** are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type.

In other words, printing `0.7000000000 0.6999999881 FLT_EVAL_METHOD=2` [is one possible behavior](http://ideone.com/VGHNjx) for the modified program below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
    float a=0.7;
    printf("%.10f %.10f FLT_EVAL_METHOD=%d\n",0.7f, a, (int)FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
    return 0;
}
```

Because the compiler defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to `2`, `printf("%.10f %.10f", 0.7f, 0.7)` is treated as if it was `printf("%.10f %.10f", (double)0.7L, (double)0.7L)`. Similarly, `printf("%.60Lf %.60Lf\n", (long double)0.7f, (long double)0.7)` is equivalent to `printf("%.60Lf %.60Lf\n", 0.7L, 0.7L)`.

Comment: What is the difference between double and long float?

Comment: @PaulStelian there is no “long float” in C. There is a `long double` type that is the same as `double` on some platforms and is mapped to the 80-bit IEEE 754-like format originally implemented in the 8087. This is the representation used for all constants and intermediate floating-point results in the compiler from ideone.com.

Comment: Well, the "%Lf" thing confused me, that's why. The CPU registers in a FPU (I'm not sure how the SSE implementation works) would be 80-bit indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get different values is that, as you are passing to `printf(3)` (which is a vararg function) as an unchecked parameter, the compiler *does* a cast to `(double)` (and an optimization i'm guessing) converting the `0.7f` literal to a `0.7D` *before passing it to `printf`*, so you are actually passing **two different values to printf**, the first is `(double)0.7f`, and the second is the stored value of variable `a`, converted to a `(double)`.